# CPAN - Specio::Constraint::Simple install error

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

Attempting to install [Specio::Constraint::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Specio::Constraint::Simple), running into the following error:

> Can't resolve method "???" overloading "&{}" in package
>   "Specio::Constraint::Simple" at Specio::Constraint::Simple->new line
>   35.

Only related article I have found has been: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=117975

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It sure looks like it's the same issue that's documented in that very recent RT.

Comment: Same issue: http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/dc685bca-6bf8-1014-86c7-0a1de40d07e9

Comment: This may be a bug in older versions of [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny) that was [fixed in 1.003003](https://metacpan.org/source/HAARG/Role-Tiny-2.000003/Changes#L27). Which version of Role::Tiny do you have? Does upgrading it fix it?

Comment: @melpomene Holy script, that fixed it!  Thanks for the assistance, it is *very* much appreciated.  Can you add that as an answer and I'll mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in older versions of [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny) that was [fixed in version 1.003003](https://metacpan.org/source/HAARG/Role-Tiny-2.000003/Changes#L27):

> - overloads specified as method names rather than subrefs are now applied
>     properly

Upgrading Role::Tiny should fix it and allow Specio::Constraint::Simple to be installed normally.

Actually, you don't even need to do that manually: Version 0.26 of Specio [now requires at least version 1.003003 of Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/changes/release/DROLSKY/Specio-0.26#L1). Any future attempt to install Specio will upgrade Role::Tiny automatically (if required).